# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library : cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, php, shared-library

I'm trying to compile a specific version of [GEOS](https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos) and its [PHP bindings](https://github.com/libgeos/php-geos) in the [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/) environment; they're using Ubuntu.

Here is my install script:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get remove 'libgeos.*'
sudo apt-get autoremove

wget https://github.com/libgeos/libgeos/archive/$VERSION.tar.gz
tar zxf $VERSION.tar.gz
cd libgeos-$VERSION
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
cd ..

wget https://git.osgeo.org/gogs/geos/php-geos/archive/1.0.0rc1.tar.gz
tar zxf 1.0.0rc1.tar.gz
cd php-geos
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
mv modules/geos.so $(php-config --extension-dir)
cd ..

echo "extension=geos.so" > geos.ini
phpenv config-add geos.ini
```

Everything seems to compile fine, but when PHP attempts to load the GEOS extension, this message appears:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.6.28/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226/geos.so' - libgeos_c.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

I've executed this command on the machine:

```
sudo find / -name 'libgeos_c.so*'
```

And here is the result:

```
/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1.9.0
/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so.1
/usr/local/lib/libgeos_c.so
/home/travis/build/brick/geo/libgeos-3.5.0/capi/.libs/libgeos_c.so.1.9.0T
/home/travis/build/brick/geo/libgeos-3.5.0/capi/.libs/libgeos_c.so.1.9.0
/home/travis/build/brick/geo/libgeos-3.5.0/capi/.libs/libgeos_c.so.1
/home/travis/build/brick/geo/libgeos-3.5.0/capi/.libs/libgeos_c.so
```

So it looks like the freshly built GEOS PHP extension is trying to load the shared object file from another location than `/usr/local/lib`.

**How can I fix this?**

Here is the [full log on Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/brick/geo/builds/182815142).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to make the extension look for the shared libraries in `/usr/local/lib`, but I did find a way to make libgeos install them to `/usr/lib`, which is where the extension is looking for them.

Just use `--prefix` when building libgeos:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer version, PHP bindings is now a standalone project, so `ldconfig` must be run between after build of `libgeos` and `php-geos` for PHP module to load dynamic libraries from `libgeos` properly.